# Beanstalkd server unavailable issue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, beanstalkd

I'm wanting to use beanstalkd with Laravel 4, so I can queue my mail for sending. I noticed that laravel 4 has beanstalkd ready to roll out of the box (with a few config settings to set). My issue if with using a GUI to monitor beanstalkd. I've installed both phpBeanstalkdAdmin and beanstalkd_console. When I access beanstalkd_console in my browser, all displays well, but I'm getting this error:

> Errors: The server is unavailable

and with phpBeanstalkdAdmin I'm getting only the admin interface, and none of the buttons work. I can't apply a server, I can't add any jobs to any tubes throught their interface.

The command I'm using to run beanstalkd on my ubuntu 12.10 server is:

> beanstalkd -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11300

This command appears to work fine and the server runs or starts monitoring.

I've checked the confif option in beanstalkd_console's include.php and all settings are correct. Has anyone experienced a similar problem, or know what the cause might be?

Comment: Is the PHP/webserver on the same machine as the Beanstalkd server?

Comment: Yes the PHP/webserver and beanstalkd are on the same machine/server.

Answer (score 0):

try to run with verbose to see if anything wrong with beanstalkd itself or the connection

`beanstalkd -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11300 -V`

or more verbose with -VV (big V)